# Calling an ActiveX method from javascript in Outlook webview

Tags: javascript, c#, html, outlook, activex

SO community

I'm currently writing a project to integrate some custom views and forms in Outlook.
The idea is to create an Outlook extension connected to our ERP.
As discovered in this sample project (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479346.aspx), one technique is to build an ActiveX component and load it from a lightweight local html page, like this :

```
<html>
    <body rightmargin = '0' leftmargin ='0' topmargin ='0' bottommargin = '0' onload='OnBodyLoad()'>
    <object classid='clsid:f746a8b6-3659-4f4c-8518-6336187854f2' ID='MyView' VIEWASTEXT width='100%' height='100%'/>
    <script>
        function OnBodyLoad() {
            try {
                var oApp = window.external.OutlookApplication;
                var view = document.getElementById('MyView');
                view.Initialize(oApp);
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert(err.description);
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the Outlook application instance is passed to the Initialize() method for further access from the ActiveX (this is the important point for me).

The C# class looks like this :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("F746A8B6-3659-4F4C-8518-6336187854F2")]
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
        :base()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String Str { get; set; }


    public void Initialize(Object app)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Initialized");
        //MessageBox.Show(app.Version);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "It works!");
    }
}
```

It's signed and registered with RegAsm.
When I load it in IE, it works like a charm. I get the message "Initialized" at startup, and when I click on button1, the message "It works" pops up too.

BUT (there is of course a 'but' :) when I load this page in Outlook (folder properties / home page), the ActiveX component gets loaded and visible, but the Initialize call throws this error: "Object doesn't support this property or method". Clicking the button1 works.

Trying to assign something to the property from Str with javascript fails in Outlook too, and works in IE.

Did anyone here face the same problem, and knows what I'm missing?

Many thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Comment: I'm facing the very same issue. I saw your other post on MSDN but the answer is not what i expected. Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I abandoned this approach. It's a shame because it was very promising :(